# ¿Cambiar el color al seleccionar una opción?

Tags: php, javascript, bootstrap

Tengo un listado con unas opciones de: Bueno, Regular y Malo. Lo que quiero hacer, con PHP y Bootstrap, es que cuando se seleccione (por ejemplo, Bueno), todo el recuadro se ponga de color verde; cuando seleccione Regular, cambie a amarillo, pero quiero que cambie de color todo el div que lo contiene. No sé si haya forma de hacerlo.

```
<select  class="form-control" name='canon'>
  <div class="list-group">
    <option  <?php if($fila['canon']=='Bueno'){ echo "selected";}?> value="Bueno">Bueno </option>
    <option  <?php if($fila['canon']=='Regular'){ echo "selected";}?> value="Regular">Regular</option>
    <option  <?php if($fila['canon']=='Malo'){ echo "selected";}?> value="Malo">Malo</option>
    <option  <?php if($fila['canon']=='No posee'){ echo "selected";}?> value="No posee">No Posee</option>
  </div>
</select>
```

Quiero que al seleccionar alguna de estas opciones, todo el select se ponga del color, es decir, todo el select se ponga verde al seleccionar bueno, pero sólo al seleccionarlo cambie de color.

Comment: **[Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)**. lee 
**[cómo crear una buena pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)** y **[¿sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)**. Debes [edit] y mejorar tu pregunta. Agrega en la pregunta qué has intentado, qué errores tienes, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En primer lugar, **no podés poner un `<div />` adentro de un `<select />`**.

Habiendo aclarado lo anterior, mi sugerencia es vincular el evento `onchange` del `<select />` para que asigne una clase al contenedor, de la siguiente forma:

```js
function colorChange(e){
  let div = e.parentNode;
  switch(e.value){
    case 'bueno':
      div.style.backgroundColor = "green";
      break;
    case 'regular':
      div.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
      break;
    case 'malo':
      div.style.backgroundColor = "red";
      break;
    default:
      div.style.backgroundColor = "";
      break;
  }
}
```

```css
.contenedor {
  padding: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="contenedor">
  <select onchange="colorChange(this)">
    <option value="">Seleccione una opción</option>
    <option value="bueno">Bueno</option>
    <option value="regular">Regular</option>
    <option value="malo">Malo</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="contenedor">
  <select onchange="colorChange(this)">
    <option value="">Seleccione una opción</option>
    <option value="bueno">Bueno</option>
    <option value="regular">Regular</option>
    <option value="malo">Malo</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Usando la propiedad `parentNode` del elemento que ejecuta el llamado a la función (a través de la llamada `colorChange(this)`, enviando el elemento como parámetro) podemos, de forma dinámica, cambiar el color únicamente del contenedor del `<select />` que cambia de valor.

Comment: Ya lo hice, era eso mismo, gracias amigo, muy amable...

Comment: tengo otra duda, si quisiera agregar eso mismo a varios selects, como lo haría?, por que sólo me toma el primer select...

Comment: Solo debés incluir la llamada a la función en cualquier select que querás usar. Modifiqué el código para que tome el contenedor del select en cuestión.

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo, me has ayudado bastante, eres muy amable...

Comment: Si tu problema ha sido resuelto, [marca la respuesta como aceptada](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) para que informar a otros usuarios que la respuesta solucionó tu problema.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías hacer algo así:

```
<script>
function setStatus(elem, key) {
    elem.setAttribute("class", "alert alert-" + key);
}
</script>

<div class="alert alert-primary" onclick="setStatus(this, 'success')">Bueno</div>
<div class="alert alert-primary" onclick="setStatus(this, 'warning')">Regular</div>
<div class="alert alert-primary" onclick="setStatus(this, 'danger')">Malo</div>
```

Te dejo un fiddle para que lo pruebes: https://jsfiddle.net/qb8vn26L/

Comment: Más o menos esa es la idea de lo que quiero hacer, déjame lo acomodo en mi código a ver si me funciona y te comento que tal me fue.

Comment: emm, bueno, pues no pude adaptarlo, pero te pongo un poco mi codigo como quisiera que fuera..